# Чем оперирует коллекция ConcurrentBag

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Чем оперирует коллекция ConcurrentBag: ссылками или объектами? Т.е при TryTake мы удаляем ссылку на объект или копируем объект, а после удаляем его из коллекции.

Comment: ссылками - для reference типов, объектами - в случае value типов

Comment: @Igor тобишь если мы добавляем class в эту коллекцию, то при TryTake мы удаляем ссылку и получаем ссылку, так?Уточняю, чтобы наверняка.От этого зависит многое.

Comment: да (13 символов нужно...)

Comment: @Igor оформите как ответ?Вдруг понадобиться кому еще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и все остальные типы *generic* контейнеров, `ConcurrentBag` оперирует ссылками - для *reference* типов (классов), объектами - в случае *value* типов (структур).